# Can optaplanner solve partly pre-assigned planning entities using Drools rules?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

We are using the time dependent vehicle routing problem example of Optaplanner 6.2.

In our case the domain model consists of activities (corresponding to customers) and technicians (corresponding to vehicles).

Is it possible to initialize an optimization with partly pre-assigned activities to certain technicians, whereby the rest of activities is not assigned?

This would correspond to the case of optaplanner (cvrptw-case) when we stop the solving or wait for the solution, and then add at the end of the solved xml-file not assigned activities. 
This file would then be used for the further optimization as input file. Here it is **mandatory to lock the already assigned activities**.

Can such a starting state: **initially locked consecutive
chain-parts of pre-defined activities at the chain-start which should not be rearranged** - while the rest activities should be optimized and put after the pre-assigned activities into the existing chains, handled with incremental constraint rules (with Drools)?

Comment: Does this relate to [this jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-239)?

Comment: Dear Geoffrey, in principle yes, but here the initial condition is that only a part of activities is assigned (locked) and the rest not (is that the same as the jira issue described?).
Is  this jira issue only related to 6.0.1 Final?
Can such a Problem solved with 6.2.0 as user2952819 (below) mentioned it?

Answer (score 1):

Read over the Immovable Planning Entities and Nonvolatile Replanning sections of the Repeated Planning chapter of the manual.  It's fairly well explained.